# Centos 5.11 libstdc++.so.6 How update or put a newer version?

Tags: linux, centos, libstdc++

I am a system, hundreds 5:11
I'm trying to run a game server and I'm a mistake, says I lack the lib. GLIBCXX_3.4.11

> [root@571 ~]# strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.1
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.2
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.3
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.4
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.5
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.6
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.7
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.8
>
> GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW

Error: Failed (/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required

If anyone can help me, please. I will be very grateful.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly that you don't. That symbol is unlikely to exist in any version of `libstdc++` that is officially available for CentOS 5. You can compile it yourself or use a newer CentOS version that has a new enough `libstdc++`. Alternatively find a build of the server built for CentOS 5 (assuming that is possible).

Comment: it is unfortunately not possible a more current version of hundreds. For the data center told me that the 6 and 7 is not compatible with the dedicated concerned to use Intel Xeon X3450.

And I do not have a broad knowledge, my knowledge is only basic things I need to do. Only now did this problem.

If it is not too much to ask. Could you explain how I could 'compile'?

Comment: If the software is open source (or something you bought the source code for) it should have directions for that. Where did you get the binary/etc. you are trying to run from?

Comment: is a game server. GTA: SA-MP. Run from winscp. But i think it does not have source code.

EDIT: But there is one detail is not the file that I run itself. is a plugin added to this app, I think I can his source but will not know compile, or what to do with it.

Comment: You don't run programs with `scp`/`winscp`. That might be how you got it to the server though. If the source isn't available then you aren't going to be able to compile it yourself.

Comment: I found the plugin on source.
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60044532/plugin-R7-src_final.rar) But How should I continue ?

Comment: Didn't look at that too clearly but that didn't look, at first glance, to have anything to do with GTA to me. In any case that is code and would need to be compiled it looked like.

Comment: Well, I develop server GTA: SA-MP. But, I use MySQL. So in order to create a connection between the mysql functions with the necessary server from a plugin. and this plugin is that just need Glibcxx. But this plugin need the 3.4.9. But I have another plugin that requires 3.4.11, but I learned to solve a solve the other.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly or what step in the process you are stuck on. The issue is that CentOS doesn't have a new enough libstdc++. There isn't an official way to fix that. You can either get a new libstdc++ yourself, build the software for CentOS 5 (or find one built that way), or find a different server to host this on.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.x86_64
```